# Prolog exercise, identical lists

Tags: prolog

I found following exercise on www.learnprolognow.org, I tried solving it but haven't been able to:

Write a predicate `swap12(List1,List2)` which checks whether `List1` is identical to `List2`, except that the first two elements are exchanged.

What I have now:

```
swap12([X,Y],[Y,X]).
swap12([X,Y|T],[Y,X|Z]) :-
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having? You don't specify any.

Comment: @APerson I added what I currently have

Comment: You're very close. Why are the two tails (`T` and `Z`) different in your second predicate clause if they're the same list other than the first two elements swapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there: you just need to establish that the elements after the first two in each list are the same (hint: if two things can both be represented by the same variable, they are the same).  In fact, you only need one rule.

Comment: swap12([X,Y|T],[Y,X|Z] :- T=Z. ?

Comment: Are you not able to test it yourself?

Comment: Currently not behin laptop but will test in 30 minutes

Comment: @Michiel, a shorter form of what you're suggesting would be `swap12([X,Y|T], [Y,X|T]).`